# Объединение Android проектов

Tags: android

Добрый день, есть два проекта, два готовых, работающих независимо друг от друга приложения (А и В). Стоит задача объединить их в одно приложение (С), с возможностью запуска из него либо А либо В. Как лучше это сделать?

Думаю если прямо перенести одно в другое и поправить все зависимости, возможно что-то и выйдет, но не уверен что это правильный способ. Какие еще есть варианты?

Answer (score -1):

как в андроиде обращаются к другим приложениям? Через неявные интенты. Вам также надо организовать взаимодействие через неявные интенты.

Comment: Наверное я не корректно задал вопрос, у меня есть исходники 2-х приложений, пусть это будет калькулятор и плеер. Мне нужно сделать приложение, чтобы при запуске, например, была активность с возможностью выбора что запустить - плеер или калькулятор. Весь код нужно уместить в одном проекте и на выходе должен быть один апк.

Comment: Да, я Вас не правильно понял. Можно подрубить одно приложение к другому как модуль. И сделать как Вы хотите активити одно с запуском двух приложений

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?